# Why is my WCF transaction not working?

Tags: .net, wcf

I am getting following error while executing my simple wcf transaction application.

"At least one operation on the 'Service1' contract is configured with the TransactionFlowAttribute attribute set to Mandatory but the channel's binding 'BasicHttpBinding' is not configured with a TransactionFlowBindingElement. The TransactionFlowAttribute attribute set to Mandatory cannot be used without a TransactionFlowBindingElement."

My Code snippet is as follows:
Iservice1.cs

```
        [OperationContract]
        [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
        bool PerformCreditTransaction(string creditAccountID, double amount);

        [OperationContract, TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
        bool PerformDebitTransaction(string debitAccountID, double amount);
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public bool PerformCreditTransaction(string creditAccountID, double amount)
        {
           //my code
        }

        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public bool PerformDebitTransaction(string debitAccountID, double amount)
        {
            //my code
        }
```

Can any one help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

basicHttpBinding does not support transactions across the service boundary because basicHttpBinding exposes services over SOAP 1.1 which does not support WS-AtomicTransaction.

You need to use wsHttpBinding which uses SOAP 1.2 and so provides support for transactions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set an operation to `TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory`, the service and client must use a transaction aware binding and have transaction flow enabled on the binding.
For example:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding transactionFlow="true" />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The following post contains additional information:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38793/Steps-to-Enable-Transactions-in-WCF

Note:  You may want to provide the binding configuration in the question to help generate more specific answers.